# loop in sql to update record as per user

Tags: sql-server, loops, stored-procedures

I have 2 tables in my `sql server` in 1st table I am saving official holidays(`officialHolidays`) and in second table I am saving Leave Applied by users(`appliedLeave`),

I stored all the saturday's and sundays of 2018 in `officialHolidays Table`

> here is one scenerio

I have 2 users

user `A` Applied a leave from `1 dec 2018 to 10 dec 2018` so leaveApplied for this user is `7 days` as 2nd and 9th dec is sunday 8th dec is non working saturday

user `B` Applied a leave from `1 dec 2018 to 5 dec 2018` so leaveApplied for this user is `4 days` as 2nd dec is sunday

And `Dec 1` is `saturday` this saturday is working saturday as per my db but now I am giving this saturday as official holiday, I updated `officialHolidays` and now I want to update `appliedLeave` table too so that the LeaveApplied for user `A` becomes 6 and user `B` becomes 3

I want to use loops to update the reord of user A then User B

here is my update query

```
UPDATE officialHolidays SET              
Active = @Active            
WHERE OfficialID = @OfficialID
```

this is what I Tried just now

```
DECLARE @HolidayDate AS DATE = (SELECT Date FROM officialHolidays WHERE OfficialID = @OfficialID)
    IF(EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM AppliedLeave WHERE AppliedFrom BETWEEN @HolidayDate AND @HolidayDate
    OR AppliedTo BETWEEN @HolidayDate AND @HolidayDate))
BEGIN
    DECLARE @LeaveTaken AS FLOAT
    DECLARE @LeaveRemaining AS FLOAT
    --I want to add Loop Here
END
```

how can I add a loop in this scenerio?

Comment: loop in sql = bad idea. Do not use loop when they can be avoided (and most of the time they can be). SQL works best with a set based approach.

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: Finally I achieved what I wanted thanks guys for your help

Comment: No you did not. Your IF statement is completely wrong. @HolidayDate is a single, scalar value - using it as both upper and lower boundaries in a between statement is just nonsense. Using floats instead of integers to store simple numbers is not a good sign either.

Comment: @SMor leavetaken can be in digits and HolidayDate is only an example I have 2 different date to compare